# Message card flexibility. How to access job name parameter

Tags: prometheus, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to access the job_name field in the message cards, but I cannot seem to get how that to happen.
I'm using this template
https://github.com/prometheus-msteams/prometheus-msteams/blob/master/examples/templates/default-message-card.tmpl

I need to have a condition "if job_name" is blackbox " do one description, else go with the default one.

How do you also access instance names, job names of the alert in alertmanager.
I've tried to do this rule:

```
"title": "{{- if eq .labels.job "blackbox" -}}
{{.CommonLabels.alertname }} is DOWN
{{- else -}}
Prometheus Alert ({{ .Status | title }})
{{- end -}}",
```

Doesn't really work as expected

Instead of "Prometheus Firing" get "Instance is down", or Instance is UP. That will be based on the job name (which I can't seem to get how to access.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to access it using $ (dollar).

Could you please try to access the job field name like "$labels.job"

Comment: This does not come under Teams development. Could you please raise this issue at [prometheus-msteams/issues](https://github.com/prometheus-msteams/prometheus-msteams/issues)